# Create vite requires impossible version combination (18 || 20 and 16 || 17)

Tags: node.js, vite, yarnpkg

I attempted to create a vite project.

```
$ nvm use 16
Now using node v16.17.1 (npm v8.15.0)

~/play $ yarn create vite chordo --template vue
yarn create v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info @nrwl/nx-darwin-arm64@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-darwin-arm64@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-darwin-arm64@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @nrwl/nx-darwin-x64@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-darwin-x64@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-linux-arm-gnueabihf@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-linux-arm-gnueabihf@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-gnu@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-gnu@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-musl@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-musl@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-win32-arm64-msvc@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-win32-arm64-msvc@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-win32-arm64-msvc@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @nrwl/nx-win32-x64-msvc@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-win32-x64-msvc@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error create-vite@5.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^18.0.0 || >=20.0.0". Got "16.17.1"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

So it looks like I need Node version 18 or 20. So I switch to version 20 and try again:

```
~/play $ nvm use 20
Now using node v20.10.0 (npm v10.2.3)

~/play $ yarn create vite chordo --template vue
yarn create v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info @nrwl/nx-darwin-arm64@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-darwin-arm64@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-darwin-arm64@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @nrwl/nx-darwin-x64@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-darwin-x64@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-linux-arm-gnueabihf@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-linux-arm-gnueabihf@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-gnu@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-gnu@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-musl@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-linux-arm64-musl@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-win32-arm64-msvc@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-win32-arm64-msvc@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @nrwl/nx-win32-arm64-msvc@15.7.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @nrwl/nx-win32-x64-msvc@15.7.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "@nrwl/nx-win32-x64-msvc@15.7.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error @achrinza/node-ipc@9.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "8 || 10 || 12 || 14 || 16 || 17". Got "20.10.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

What is causing this situation? How can I resolve it?

I'm using Ubuntu on WSL. Yarn v 1.22.15.